# Windows phone emulator doesn't work

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone, unity-game-engine

I was just testing Unity 4.2's new feature - Windows Phone deployment, but it doesn't seem to work.
Is there any way to get it running on an emulator rather than on a physical device?

Thanks

[image]

EDIT:

I tried changing configuration to "x86" but It's now giving me another error:

I think I attempted all possible combinations, but it still doesn't work:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried changing the target? (Build -> Configuration manager ->  Platform)

Comment: @Kajzer Yes, Everything except "Device" fails, but I don't have a device :/

Comment: the error states "The output path is not set"... So is the output path set? In the project properties (not solution) click the Build tab and scroll down to the Output region and ensure that the Output path is set

Comment: @Shawn Kendrot Yes, sorry for a late reply, the output path is set correctly

Comment: @OleksiyDobrodum if you can't read the most simple of error messages, I would strongly recommend you begin with basic .NET, instead of attempting to create a game. The error messages you posted so far are very clear in their meaning.

Comment: @Claus Jørgensen If you don't have anything useful to say, please be quiet. I would strongly recommend you find a different hobby than being useless at stackoverflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the reference errors you are getting could mean that those classes aren't compatible with your architecture.

Comment: It turns out that you're right - it's currently impossible to test Unity games on emulators; only real devices work.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to deploy an ARM native binary to an x86 "phone". You will need to compile your project for the x86 CPU architecture for it to work on the emulator.

Make sure that you change your "Solution Platforms" from "AnyCPU", "Mixed Platforms" or "ARM" to "x86" and re-build your project.

You should find that the "Debug Target" switches automatically from "Device" to "Emulator WVGA 512MB" once you change the Solution Platform.

You may have to unhide the option to switch between CPU architectures in in Visual Studio 2012. In the Standard Toolbar options make sure that the "Solution Platforms" control is visible in your toolbar.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response, I tried many different ways to set it up, but it's still not working. Could you please look at my screenshots and tell me what I'm doing wrong? By the way, there is no such option as "Win32"

Comment: You've got "Active Solution Platform" set to x86 and UnityGame set to ARM. Change UnityGame to x86. "Win32" keeps creeping into my old projects, but x86 is a better description :)

Comment: I changed UnityGame to x86 (now both are x86), but it keeps showing me this error: "The Output path property is not set for project 'UnityGame.csproj' .... and so on.

Comment: The screenshot shows the solution platform as "Any CPU". "Any CPU" != "x86.

Comment: Sorry, that's an old screenshot, I did everything as you said this time, But the error doesn't change; I'll upload the nw screenshot

Answer (score 0):

Please check the path. In the solution explorer if it is showing any missing files, fix them by adding existing items. It seems like you are missing dll files also.

Answer (score 0):

> Registered Windows Phone 8 device is needed to test your apps.
>   Instructions on phone registration can be found here. Windows Phone
>   Emulator will be supported in future Unity releases.

https://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Manual/wp8-gettingstarted.html

Answer (score -1):

in my opinion you should check the localizedString first, after that set up your IP of Emulator

Comment: Sorry, I don't exactly understand what exactly is localizedString and how it could help me run a Unity game on a Windows phone. Could you elaborate please?